# UITextView in UITableViewCell prevents segue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextview, segue

I have many UITableViewCells that mainly consist of UITextViews.

Now the problem is that when clicking on a cell it does not initiate `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

This has made it hard for me to be able to segue to another VC.

I have tried numerous things, one of which was to add tap gesture recognizers and then try to manually segue by using `-presentViewController:` I had some issues there too. Is there a more general and easy way to do this? I also need is to pass some values to the viewController that I am going to show.

**EDIT**

This is what i was trying with using gestures:

```
func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let tapLocation = sender.locationInView(self.tableView)

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(tapLocation)

    let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPushID")
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)
    self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Using this method above here works but i cant/dont know how to pass parameters to some variables i have on the controller.

This method:

```
    let destinationVC = showPushNotificationMessage()
    destinationVC.pushMessage = "test"
    destinationVC.dateOpened = "test"


    presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Give me this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @UmairAfzal updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty simple dude :). Method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns `UIViewController` so if you want to access variable of your `UIViewController`, just typecast you return type as below.

**How to pass data to your viewcontroller**

```
let destinationVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPushID") as! YourDestinationViewController
destinationVC.pushMessage = "test"
destinationVC.dateOpened = "test"
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
self.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Not sure the purpose of taking TextView on your cell but you can create the delegate methods for your CustomTableCell and then on tap you can call your delegate method, follow the steps

**Create Delegate Method**

```
@objc protocol MyCustomCellDelegate
{
    func textViewTapped(cell : MyCustomTableViewCell)
}
```

**Custom Table View Cell**

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
@IBOutlet weak var myTextView : UITextView!
weak var delegate : MyCustomCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    myTextView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:))))
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.delegate?.textViewTapped(self)
}
}
```

**In your ViewController** inherit `MyCustomCellDelegate` as you are doing with `UITableViewDelegate`
and write the delegate method to your viewcontroller

```
func textViewTapped(cell: MyCustomTableViewCell)
{
    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myDestView")
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

set cell delegate in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

```
cell.delegate = self
```

**Access your cell as**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as! AssessmentTableViewCell
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you man. Also just edit your answer: you write self.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated:true, completion: nil),  where instead of destinationVC it should be navController

Comment: Happy to help buddy